# Iterating through jFrame components

Tags: netbeans-plugins

I have a frame with a jPanel, a button and about 50 jTextFields in it. I need to write an array one item in one jTextField on button click event. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ActionListioner` and add an array item in it like this:

```
class MyFrame{

    private int i=0;
    private JTextField jTextField;
    private JButton jButton;
    MyFrame(){

            jButton = new JButton("Click");
            jTextField = new JTextField();
            jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            jTextField.setText(arry[i]);
                            i+=1;
                    }
            });
    }
```

}